# Can I use type traits to deduce the type of an enum from an enum value in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, enums

In the example below I have created some fluent methods templated on enum values  that test if a value contains a specific flag.

```
#include <type_traits>

// Scoped flags enum
enum class Flags {
    One = 1 << 0,
    Two = 1 << 1
};

// Template method for enum bitwise and operator
template< typename enum_type >
constexpr enum_type bitwise_and_operator(enum_type lhs, enum_type rhs) {
    typedef typename std::underlying_type<enum_type>::type fundamental_type;
    return static_cast<enum_type>(static_cast<fundamental_type>(lhs) & static_cast<fundamental_type>(rhs));
}

// Flags and operator
constexpr Flags operator&(Flags lhs, Flags rhs) {
    return bitwise_and_operator<Flags>(lhs, rhs);
}

// Template method for enum flag
template< typename enum_type, enum_type enum_value >
constexpr bool Flagged(enum_type type) {
    return (type & enum_value) == enum_value;
}

// Has flag one?
constexpr bool HasOne(Flags flags) {
    return Flagged<Flags, Flags::One>(flags);
};

// Has flag two?
constexpr bool HasTwo(Flags flags) {
    return Flagged<Flags, Flags::Two>(flags);
};


int main() {

    auto flag = Flags::One;

    auto True = HasOne(flag);
    auto False = HasTwo(flag);

    return 0;
}
```

Including both template parameters, Flags and Flags::One, is possibly more information than the compiler requires.

Is it possible to construct a template that could be called as:

```
constexpr bool HasOne(Flags flags) {
    return Flagged<Flags::One>(flags);
};
```

How would I construct a method that deduces the enum type from the value at compile time?  Or is there another compile time solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see the need for the value being a template parameter.

Comment: Thanks chris, it is not a _need_ but rather part of an effort to move as more computation from run time to compile time.  A series of precomputable types can be extremely helpful when performance is important.  Also, to use operator overloading and not be dependent on the underlying type, I believe the template parameter on type is required...but yes there are more general ways to accomplish the comparison at compile time.  Furthermore, the example given is purely a demonstration of the extra information handed to the compiler.  Do you have an answer for the traits question?

Comment: You're not getting any more compile-time information by making that a template parameter given your function body. If the other argument is known at compile-time, then the result of the function can be used at compile-time. That's how `constexpr` works. My template type argument was in reference to using `bitwise_and_operator<Flags>` instead of letting it deduce the type. Type deduction should be preferred where possible instead of doing the compiler's work for it. If `Flagged` changes to have only the type as a template parameter, `HasOne` can also get rid of its `Flags` template argument.

Comment: chris thanks for your answer but what if I explicitly want to do the compilers work?  I am a fan of relying on the compiler to do my work for me but there can be advantage in specifying the methods directly.  But yes, we could make some fancier version of the operator functions that are more general.  Either way I would still appreciate a way to determine the enum type from the enum value and create the requested method in the above example.

Comment: I don't see the logic. You prefer explicitly giving the type to functions that can deduce it, e.g., `bitwise_and_operator<Flags>`, yet you prefer the compiler deducing the type to do `Flagged<Flags::One>(...)` instead of `Flagged<Flags, Flags::One>`. Yes, saying `Flags` twice here is annoying. So is saying `Flags` yet again for the `bitwise_and_operator` call after already specifying `Flags` as a type for each parameter. That's just as redundant. One day, you're going to do the compiler's work and get it wrong. One popular example is `for (const pair<K, V> &p : map)`, which copies each pair.

Comment: Anyway, could you maybe give an example of why Barry's answer won't work for you? It's perfectly capable of executing at compile-time given a proper argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, only with a macro:

```
 #define FLAGGED(x,y) Flagged<decltype(x),x>(y)
```

There is a [proposal in the works](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4469.html) to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for including the link.

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you want `enum_value` as a template parameter? You could simply pass it as another argument:

```
template <typename enum_type>
constexpr bool Flagged(enum_type src, enum_type flag) {
    return (src & flag) == flag;
}

// Has flag one?
constexpr bool HasOne(Flags flags) {
    return Flagged(flags, Flags::One);
};
```

Comment: Thanks Barry.  I believe we could use constexpr to produce similar code using a _normal_ function definition but there is some advantage in directly specifying the compile time information.  Flagged<Flags::One>(flags) explicitly states what information is compile time and which information is open to be done at runtime (flags).  That can be useful.